# NPE on Listview Textview onclicklistener

Tags: java, android, listview

I have written below code When I use only thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  , code works fine. As soon as I add one more method i.e. vdownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(), it start giving NPE on vdownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener().why both are not working together.

here is my code:

```
public class YouTubeCustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    private List<YouTubeMov> youTubeMov;
    private int idgot;



    public YouTubeCustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<YouTubeMov> youTubeMovs, int id) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.youTubeMov = youTubeMovs;
        this.idgot = id;

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return youTubeMov.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return youTubeMov.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        System.out.println("Launched");
        if (layoutInflater == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        if (convertView == null)
            if (idgot == 1) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubecustomlistmains, null);
            } else {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.youtubecustomlist, null);
            }

        if (imageLoader == null)
            imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titles);
        TextView totalviews = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.totalviews);
        TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
        TextView vdownload = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vdownlay);
        thumbNail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Popup.smallpopup("Text", activity);
                YouTubeMov dm = youTubeMov.get(position);
                String vid = dm.getId();
                System.out.println(vid);
                                       Intent intent = new Intent(activity, MyYouTube.class);
                      intent.putExtra("videoid", vid);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);

                                }
        });

        vdownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              // code to Work    
            }
        });

        if (idgot == 1) {
            movieId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.movieid);
        }
        TextView duration = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.duration);
        // getting movie data for the row
        YouTubeMov tubeMov = youTubeMov.get(position);

        //  thumbnail image
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(tubeMov.getThumbnailurl(), imageLoader);


        // title
        title.setText(tubeMov.getTitle());
        System.out.println("Got Title " + tubeMov.getTitle());
        // Total Views
        totalviews.setText("Total Views: " + String.valueOf(tubeMov.getViews()));

        // genre
        genre.setText("Genre: " + String.valueOf(tubeMov.getChannel()));

        // release year
        /*if (idgot == 1) {
            movieId.setText("Id: " + (tubeMov.getId()));
        }
*/
        duration.setText("Time: " + tubeMov.getDuration());

        return convertView;
    }





}
```

Here is error log:

```
  Process: jss.smartapp, PID: 1052
                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Has `activity` been initialised?

Comment: share your crash log with question

Comment: pls check code now as I got error again but case is different now. it was not intent issue, it was using two methods together. pls help

Comment: Does your both individual layouts have this textView `vdownlay` id?

Comment: one layout has thumbnail  NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
and other has Textview TextView vdownload = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.vdownlay);

Comment: your question gave ultimate clue which I missed, actually I was using same class for two different layouts and other layout was not having vdownlay textview . It is fixed now. thanks